# Determine which version of a package npm will pick for a given version range

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

When I run `npm install react@^15`, it automatically picks the max version satisfying `^15`.  Is there a CLI command or Node API I can use to determine which version `npm` would install, without actually installing it?

I could do the following, but I'm looking for something more concise:

```
const semver = require('semver')
const {exec} = require('child-process-async')

async function resolveVersion(pkg: string, range: string): Promise<?string> {
  const result = JSON.parse((await exec(`npm view --json ${pkg} verisons dist-tags`)).stdout)
  return result['dist-tags'][range] || semver.maxSatisfying(versions, range)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [--dry-run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#description) flag:

> The --dry-run argument will report in the usual way what the install would have done without actually installing anything.

**Example:**

```
> npm install react@^15 --dry-run

+ react@15.6.2
added 18 packages in 0.673s
```